# page is getting refreshed on adding an item even when I have used ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        alert('page is loaded');
    });

    function savefun() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AddController",
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                price: $('#price').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.flag1 == true) {
                    console.debug("true");
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'DisplayController',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.price +
                        '</td><td>' + '<button id="' + item.id + '" class="btn">Delete</button>'
                    '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#delTable').append(trHTML);
                $('button').click(function() {
                    var val = $(this).attr("id");
                    console.debug("saurabh userid", val);
                    var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            productid: val
                        },
                        url: "DisplayController",
                        success: function(result) {
                            rowElement.find('td').fadeOut('3000',
                                function() {
                                    rowElement.remove();
                                });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<table id="delTable" border=1 align="center" height="150" width="200">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100">Product Name</th>
            <th width="100">Price</th>
            <th width="100">Id</th>
            <th width="100">Delete</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>


    </tbody>
</table>

<h3 align="center">Add a New Product</h3>
<form>
    Product Name : <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
       Product Price : <input id="price" type="number" name="price">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" align="middle" onclick="savefun()">
</form>
```

I am trying to add a product/item using an AJAX call. I have written `savefun()` for to do this. When I add a product, the page is getting refreshed which should not happen, it should add without refreshing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've shown is `savefun()` called...?

Answer (score 0):

If you change button `onclick` to form `onsubmit` and `return false` from `savefun()` function.

```
<form onsubmit="return savefun();">
    Product Name : <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    Product Price : <input id="price" type="number" name="price">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" align="middle">
</form>
```

```
function savefun() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "AddController",
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            price: $('#price').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.flag1 == true) {
                console.debug("true");
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

But there is other ways to do it using jQuery.

```
$('[yourFormSelector]').on('submit', function(event){
    savefun();
    event.preventDefault();
})
```